# How do I put double spaces in batch file variables?

Tags: batch-file

So, I've been trying to write games using batch files, and typically I write something like

```
set a-1-1=  &set a-1-2=  
set a-2-1=  &set a-2-2=
```

, then to access it I use

```
set a-%x%-%y%=11
```

The problem is I can't store a double space in these variables.

Comment: Best practice for assigning a value to a variable is to use quotes. `set "var=  "` This assigns two spaces to the variable `var`.

Comment: This is a batch file, there is rarely a need, _(and it makes it harder to read and understand)_, to try to put more than one command on the same line. Then you should have four individual commands, using the recommended syntax, `Set "a-1-1=  "`, `Set "a-1-2=  "`, `Set "a-2-1=  "`, and `Set "a-2-2=  "`. To match that recommended syntax, `set a-%x%-%y%=11` should read as `Set "a-%x%-%y%=11"`. BTW, in order to get focused help for a specific issue, please provide a [MCVE] of some code which exhibits it, and sufficient supporting information for us to assist. Take a look at [ask] to assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very helpful to know what your use case is - the type of game you are attempting to make, the output you are trying to achieve, how you intend to use the array.
Is it just for output? For Collision Detection?

As regards to options for defining and using arrays in batch, familiarise yourself with `Delayed expansion`, `For` loops and `substring modificiation` - as they are batches best tools for the job.

- **Open cmd.exe and read the output of**:

  - `Setlocal /?`
  - `Set /?`
  - `for /?`

Delayed expansion allows for a neat little trick where you can define commands that reference array values before the values are actually assigned by Defining them with `!` expansion prior to actually enabling Delayed Expansion. Such Commands as variables in Batch are refered to as Macros.

Here's an example of using defining and using arrays via batch macro's within a game of Tic Tac Toe.

```bat
:start ::: [ * Author: T3RRY * ] Creation Date - 12/01/2021 ::: WINDOWS 10 only
@Echo off & mode 50,11

:# Define Virtual Termnal Escape Character. Requires Windows 10
 For /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd')do Set "\E=%%a"

Set LF=^

%= ! linefeed var. Do not remove or modify this line or above 2 lines ! =%

:# Clear the screen and Define the GRID macro for display of the playfield
 CLS & Set "Grid=<nul Set /P "=%\E%[2;13H%\E%[37mDraw       %\E%[34mWin        %\E%[33mLose%\E%[5;1H!Spacer!%\E%[?25l%\E%[0m%\E%[35m%\E%[0m%\E%[35m[%\E%[90m!c7:7=%\E%[7m7!%\E%[0m%\E%[35m][%\E%[90m!c8:8=%\E%[7m8!%\E%[0m%\E%[35m][%\E%[90m!c9:9=%\E%[7m9!%\E%[0m%\E%[35m]!LF!!Spacer![%\E%[90m!c4:4=%\E%[7m4!%\E%[0m%\E%[35m][%\E%[90m!c5:5=%\E%[7m5!%\E%[0m%\E%[35m][%\E%[90m!c6:6=%\E%[7m6!%\E%[0m%\E%[35m]!LF!!Spacer![%\E%[90m!c1:1=%\E%[7m1!%\E%[0m%\E%[35m][%\E%[90m!c2:2=%\E%[7m2!%\E%[0m%\E%[35m][%\E%[90m!c3:3=%\E%[7m3!%\E%[0m%\E%[35m]%\E%[0m""

:# Define reset macro used to flag game end state and reset the enviroment for next game
 Set "Reset=( Title #. Game over. ) & Timeout /t 3 /Nobreak > nul & Endlocal & Goto :start"

:# Defines a Macro to Iterate over winning cells ; used in assesing moves and gamestate
 Set "?.Cells=For %%V in ("!c1!!c4!!c7!" "!c2!!c5!!c8!" "!c3!!c6!!c9!" "!c1!!c2!!c3!" "!c4!!c5!!c6!" "!c7!!c8!!c9!" "!c3!!c5!!c7!" "!c1!!c5!!c9!")Do "

:# Enable Environment for Macro Expansion
 Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:# Define custom or Default Characters for Player 1 and AI

 If not "%~2" == "" (
  Set "P1=%~1"& Set "P2=%~2"& Set "P1=!P1:~-1!"& Set "P2=!P2:~-1!"
 )Else ( Set "P1=X"& Set "P2=O" )

:# Define Move List 'Cho' and initial Cell state for c1 - c9
 Set "Cho= 123456789"& Set "turn=9"& For /L %%n in (1 1 9)Do Set "c%%n=%%n"

:# Offset playfield from screen Edge [used in Grid Macro]
 For /L %%n in (1 1 20)Do Set "Spacer= !Spacer!"

:# Randomise starting Player
 For /F "Delims=" %%v in ('set /A "!random! %%2 + 1"')Do Goto p%%v

:p1

 %GRID% & TITLE Enter a number - Available: %Cho% or [E]xit

 For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('Choice /N /C:%Cho: =%e')Do (
  Set "c%%G=!P1!"
  Set "Cho=!Cho:%%G=!"
  Set /A turn-=1
  If %%G == E Exit /b 0
 )

 %GRID:90=32% & Call :Delay 2> nul

:p2

 TITLE Tic Tac Toe & %?.Cells% If "%%~V" == "!p1!!p1!!p1!" Goto :Win

 Set "move=" & Set "line="
 %?.Cells% For %%c in (!P1! !P2!)Do (
  Set "line=%%~V"
  For /L %%n in (1 1 9)Do ( :# Test ideal move; Priority - Take win ; block player
   Set "line=!line:%%n%%c%%c=!"
   If not "!line!" == "" Set "line=!line:%%c%%n%%c=!"
   If not "!line!" == "" Set "line=!line:%%c%%c%%n=!"
   If "!line!" == "" (Set "move=%%n")
 ))

 Call :AI "!P2!" && %GRID:90=31% & Call :Delay 2> nul

 %?.Cells% If "%%~V" == "!p2!!p2!!p2!" Goto :Lose

 If !turn! LEQ 0 ( %GRID:90=37% & %Reset:#=Draw% )Else Goto p1

:AI [ Enact best available move option win; block player win; centre; random ]

 If not "%move%" == "" (
  Set "c%move%=%~1"
  Set "Cho=!Cho:%move%=!"
  Set /A "turn-=1"
  Exit /B 0
 )

 Set "tCho=!Cho:5=!"
 If Not "!tCho!" == "!Cho!" (
  Set "c5=%~1"
  Set "Cho=!Cho:5=!"
  Set /A "turn-=1"
  Exit /B 0
 )

 For /F "Delims=" %%v in ('set /A "!random! %%!turn! + 1" 2^> nul ')Do (
  For %%i in ("!Cho:~%%v,1!")Do If not "!Cho:~%%v,1!" == " " If "!c%%~i!" == "%%~i" (
   Set "c%%~i=%~1" & Set "Cho=!Cho:%%~i=!" & Set /A "turn-=1"
   Exit /B 0
 ))

 If !turn! EQU 0 (Exit /B 0)Else Goto :AI

:Win
 %Grid:90=34% & %Reset:#=You Won%

:Lose
 %Grid:90=33% & %Reset:#=You Lost%
```

The Display macro `Grid` Is defined referencing the array variables for the Grid Move state. As Moves are made, Occupied cells c1 to c9 are redifined. Because the macro is defined using delayed expansion to expand the variables, but before to Delayed Expansion is actually enabled, when the macro is expanded, it expands with the current value of the c1 to c9 cel array.

Substring modification is used to update the information displayed in the Grid Array after each change.

Substring modification is also used in conjunction with An if condition to compare winning cell lines Defined in the `?Cells` macro against the definitions of the current cell array to see if lines are complete or alost complete as a means of determining move action and gamestate.

Comment: It's a 2D array, so I assume it's for the game map

Comment: Color handling is done using [virtual terminal sequences.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) changes in color as the game progresses is done using Substring modification of the GRID macro to supply the new color sequences to be displayed. Virtual terminal sequences are also used for moving the cursor position and hiding the cursor.